# How can I add a field after the table in my Woocommerce new order email template?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

In woocommerce I would like to add 2 pieces of information to email_after_order_table. How can i eat it? Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

Is it in file `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`?
If it is you can create hook in your functions file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'your_example_function', 90, 4 );
function your_example_function( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // code
}
```

That function `your_example_function` will start after action `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` inside email-order-details.php.

Comment: What code do I need to write to add a new column to the code field?

Comment: Any html will print after last table inside `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`. If you want to edit table you can [edit this file](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1)